# Há uma maneira em ASP.Net MVC, na controller acessar uma variável na sessionstorage ou localstorage?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, localstorage

Preciso obter o valor de uma variável armazenada na *sessionstorage* através de uma *controller* onde este método não é passado o parâmetro desta variável.

*Session/localstorage* são administradas através de javascript. Em situações contrária é fácil obter o valor de variáveis em C# através de AJAX e diversas outras formas.

Mas o que preciso é o contrário. Tem como fazer?

Answer (score 4):

Você pode usar o [SignalR](http://signalr.net/), que é um projeto desenvolvido pela Microsoft para que o servidor possa se comunicar com o browser, e enviar informações para o mesmo, e depois de volta para o servidor.

É possível instalar o SignalR via NuGet:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR
```

Ou pelo package manager do Visual Studio.

O SignalR é muito fácil de usar, [existe um tutorial para usar o SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-20).

Para pode pegar um valor no browser, você terá de enviar uma mensagem para o browser, e ao ouvir essa mensagem no client, enviar uma outra mensagem para o servidor, com o valor desejado.

Comment: @MarcosFreitas Que bom que você gostou das respostas! Mas a melhor forma de agradecer quem te ajudou é assinalando a melhor resposta e votando em todas que te ajudaram. Assim você garante que quem escreveu a resposta receba algo em troca, além de tornar o site mais limpo e útil pra todo mundo. Adicionar uma nova resposta assim (que não é uma resposta pra pergunta) deixa o site mais confuso e pode atrapalhar.

Comment: Miguel, dá para postar um pequeno exemplo? o conteúdo do tutorial só mostra um exemplo de bate-papo.